# Wordpress admin error when adjusting certain plugins - "get_themes is deprecated"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

As a Wordpress/PHP newbie, I'm confused.  When I try to do some things in my WP admin, for instance, when I go into my W3 Total Cache settings and check off the minify / enable button, then save the settings, I get the following error (7 of them, all the same):

```
Notice: get_theme is deprecated since version 3.4! Use wp_get_theme( $stylesheet )  
instead. in /home/jpweber/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2824

Notice: get_themes is deprecated since version 3.4! Use wp_get_themes() instead. in 
/home/jpweber/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2824
```

I get this error doing other things while in admin, as well.  I'm running WP 3.5, and it's just a vanilla install, so it's just the functions.php that came with the installation, and W3 Total Cache comes with the 1-click installation the shared host I'm with provides.

Here's my line 2824 in functions.php:

```
trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! 
Use %3$s instead.'), $function, $version, $replacement ) );
```

The complete block of code for that is as follows:

```
function _deprecated_function( $function, $version, $replacement = null ) {

do_action( 'deprecated_function_run', $function, $replacement, $version );

// Allow plugin to filter the output error trigger
if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'deprecated_function_trigger_error', true ) ) {
    if ( ! is_null($replacement) )
        trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> 
since version %2$s! Use %3$s instead.'), $function, $version, $replacement ) );
    else
        trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> 
since version %2$s with no alternative available.'), $function, $version ) );
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a plugin or template which use the "get_theme" function as stated above, whereas it should not use it anymore.

You can set "wp_debug" to false to "hide" the error, see how to do that here : 
http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

But the best thing to do would be to update all your plugins/templates, or tell the authors that you got this mistake if they did not update their code since then ;).

Comment: Thanks Melvin; I edited my wp-config file, and the error disappeared.  Does that mean the minify feature won't be working, just because I hid the error? Thanks again for taking the time to help!

Comment: You're welcome! The fact that you hid the error does not affect the behavior, it just hides the display of the error. The fact it is deprecated means the author of the W3 "Total Cache" plugin should change the code of his plugin and use the  "wp_get_themes()" function instead of  "get_themes()".

You can send him a twit' and let him know about that :
https://twitter.com/w3edge

or drop a message here:
http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/w3-total-cache